# discord.js node.js - bot reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, reply

I've created my own discord bot for my server and i want to answer me if i say specific words who are in array **tabHello** :

```
var tabHello = ['Bonjour','Salut','Hello', 'Guten tag', 'Buenos Dias'];
    var tabAnsw= ['Bonjour votre majesté.','Salutations jeune Douzien !','Ouais, ouais. T\'es qui déjà ?', 'Bonjour ' + message.author + ', comment vas-tu aujourd\'hui ?'];

    if (message.content.indexOf('Hello') > 0  && message.isMentioned(client.user)){
        var row = Math.floor(Math.random() * tabAnsw.length);
        message.channel.sendMessage(tabAnsw[row]);
    }
```

With this code, if i say "@bot Hello" he answers one value of **tabAnsw** array. But I want to answer me if i say one value of **tabHello** array.
And, if  say "Hello @bot", he doesn't answer me.

Someone can help me ?

Sorry for my english :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just use a `for` loop.

```
var tabHello = ['Bonjour','Salut','Hello', 'Guten tag', 'Buenos Dias'];
var tabAnsw = ['Bonjour votre majesté.','Salutations jeune Douzien !','Ouais, ouais. T\'es qui déjà ?', 'Bonjour ' + message.author + ', comment vas-tu aujourd\'hui ?'];
var content = message.content.split(' ');

for(var x = 0; x < content.length; x++){
    if(tabHello.includes(content[x]) && message.isMentioned(client.user)){
        var row = Math.floor(Math.random() * tabAnsw.length);
        message.channel.send(tabAnsw[row]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var tabHello = ['Bonjour','Salut','Hello', 'Guten tag', 'Buenos Dias'];
var tabAnsw= ['Bonjour votre majesté.','Salutations jeune Douzien !','Ouais, ouais. T\'es qui déjà ?', 'Bonjour ' + message.author + ', comment vas-tu aujourd\'hui ?'];

if (tabHello.indexOf(message.content) > -1  && message.isMentioned(client.user)){
    var row = Math.floor(Math.random() * tabAnsw.length);
    message.channel.sendMessage(tabAnsw[row]);
}
```

So instead of checking the message for the world hello, this checks if the message is contained within the Array.

Comment: Hi ! I tried this before coming here but no reaction from bot.

Comment: Is there anyway you can post the source of your bot somewhere or send me a github link so I can check it out and see what's wrong?

Comment: Yo can find the source of this bot here https://github.com/SalakissODV/Jollia I deleted the token

Comment: Posted a new answer with an improved version, let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

I went and made this for you, it works with Eris I tried to convert it to discord.js, it should work but not 100% sure that it will.

```
var tabHello = ['bonjour', 'salut', 'hello', 'guten tag', 'buenos dias'];
var tabAnsw = ['Bonjour votre majesté.', 'Salutations jeune Douzien !', 'Ouais, ouais. T\'es qui déjà ?', 'Bonjour ' + message.author.username + ', comment vas-tu aujourd\'hui ?'];

for (i = 0; i < tabAnsw.length; i++) {
    if (message.content.startsWith(client.user.mention) && message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf(tabHello[i])) {
        var row = Math.floor(Math.random() * tabAnsw.length);
        message.channel.sendMessage(tabAnsw[row]);
        break;
    }
}
```

I went and converted all content of tabHello to lowercase versions so later you can ignore your user's casing, for example, if John#1234 was to enter '@Bot HeLlO' it would still work because we are ignoring casing.

Answer (score 0):

I have set up this small script so you can build your bot on top of this:

index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const commands = require('./commands');
const prefix = config.prefix;

const commandExecuter = new commands();

client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setGame('Minecraft');
    var servers = client.guilds.array().map(g => g.name).join('.');
    console.log('Bot started');
});

client.on('message', message => {
    //Check if its a command
    isBotCommand(message.content, (command) => {
        //If it is, lets execute it if we can
        if ( command ) {
            commandExecuter.execute(message, client, command);
        }
    });
});



const isBotCommand = (message, callback) => {
    //Get the first char of the message
    let firstChar = message.charAt(0);
    //If it does not equal our prefix answer that it's not a bot command
    if (firstChar !== prefix) return callback(false)
    //We got here, so it seems to be a command
    return callback(message.substring(1));
}

client.login(config.token);
```

add a file "commands.js" to your root directory and paste the following:

```
const botCommandExecuter = function() {}

const findCommandFromStack = (command, callback) => {
    //Find the command in the commands array
    commands.some((iteratedCommand) => {
        //If our keyword is inside the currently iterated command object we have a match
        if ( iteratedCommand.keywords.indexOf(command) > -1 ) {
            //Call the callback and break the loop
            callback(iteratedCommand.action);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

botCommandExecuter.prototype.execute = (messageInstance, client, command) => {
    //Find the command
    findCommandFromStack(command, (commandToExecute) => {
        //Execute the command we found
        commandToExecute(messageInstance, client);
    });
}

//List of commands
const commands = [
    {
        keywords: ['Bonjour','Salut','Hello', 'Guten tag', 'Buenos Dias'],
        action: (message, client) => {
            var tabAnsw = ['Bonjour votre majesté.','Salutations jeune Douzien !','Ouais, ouais. T\'es qui déjà ?', 'Bonjour ' + message.author + ', comment vas-tu aujourd\'hui ?'];
            var row = Math.floor(Math.random() * tabAnsw.length);
            message.channel.sendMessage(tabAnsw[row]);
        }
    }
];

module.exports = botCommandExecuter;
```

There is still a lot of room for improvement and error handling, but I'll leave that up to you. Goodluck!